# How do I get the 4v4 insane AI kin achievement?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm trying to get the 4v4 insane ai kin achievements, but I'm having trouble with zerg. The recommended strategy is to cripple one the AI with spine crawlers, but the AI always kills them off with drones. I tried many different positions, but they always kill them off asap.

Edit: It seems that the AI was updated and is super aggressive when it sees a cheese (cannon rush, spine rush, bunker rush).

Comment: I too believe that the AIs were silently updated to counter cheeses. And i thing this is good ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the AI seems to be updated.

AI will now react if you build buildings close to it. You can still rush the AI, but the builds have to built at much larger distance.

Zerg is specific, there is a pathing bug. When you build the spine crawler in a gap between minerals in the mineral line, all the drones will try to assault it through the gap resulting in only one drone attacking at a time. I suspect that this will be patched as well.

Answer (score 1):

When fighting four zerg i found out that a good strategy was to go with 3 terran allies and as terran mass siege tanks and marines. Use the Megaton map and siege up in the center. It is very important to have some siege tanks ASAP in order to be able to wipe out the first attack. Then place your tanks at the cliffs/center and wipe the second attack. After that you need to severely cripple/destroy at least one of them, prefferably two. I used vikings for vision and sieged their main bases close to the middle. If this fails, you will probably lose since they will tech up and roll over you.

There are probably better strategies, but this one worked for me (after a few tries and a bit of luck). The reason is probably that insane AIs are very aggresive and as Zerg, they mass lings, hydras and roaches in the beginnig. Siege Tanks counter this well. Do not worry about a different strategy in the beginning, since your allies will mass infantry and the enemy will counter this with hydras, lings and roaches.

Answer (score 1):

I did this on Tempest, playing TZZZvZZZZ. Tempest is a very well-suited map for reaper harass. You can win the game by massing reapers off 1 base, killing workers and waiting for your allies to overrun them. Just be sure to micro your reapers, but with an APM over 50 you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this one last night to finish of the two Insane 4v4 Kin achievements.

As Zerg, playing ZZZZ vs PPPP on Abyss, I 6-pooled the nearest Protoss player, and harassed its mineral line. Ignored the gateways and pylons totally. It seemed to cripple this player enough that it couldn't do much.

Fortunately, the my AI players then basically steamrolled over the remaining Protoss players while I teched up to mutalisks.

Mind you, this was after several attempts. And i almost got wiped out twice.

8-\